# Android Animation Help!

Tags: android

(I am a beginner at android, so be nice!)

I am making a game for my Android phone, and I want a bitmap image to move from the top of the screen down to the bottom. I have been using canvas to draw the image onto the screen, I just am stumped to how to get it moving.

```
public void playerShip(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(chosenShip, x, y, painter);
    }
```

This may sound simple but I have tirelessly searched the web for a tutorial or example to no avail. I was hoping someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **do not** recommend writing a game as an android beginner, as writing a game, depending on what kind of game, style, and tools you use can be very tricky.

At the very basic level if you are moving a bitmap across the screen android comes with an API for translation, which changes the position of an object. Check it out here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

One thing to keep in mind if your image is an imageview, then this is considered a view and animations can be applied to it.

Other references you could use:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/animated-views.html

http://www.droidnova.com/2d-sprite-animation-in-android,471.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice! I will look into TranslationAnimations... Hopefully that should be sufficient for what I need!